# How long should it take to install Exchange Server 2007?

Tags: exchange-2007

It keeps "Importing Active Directory schema" already for 1h 20m, with CPU at 99%. And progress bar does not move.

I see related post (but not clear if they had cpu busy as well). http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesoftwareupdate/thread/f6e4bd32-15bf-456c-947f-f435fe36853e

The "Cancel" button is disabled, and the busy process is lsass.exe. Wonder if I should kill this process, or continue waiting? And how long does it take to complete this operation normally?

Product: Exchange Server 2007 with SP1 x86

Comment: "The entire installation takes approximately 30 minutes." http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/how-to-install-exchange-server-2007-in-13-easy-steps/2007-12-11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it last night... SP3, though. It took 22 minutes.

Comment: I stopped my vmware, added some more memory (396 mb -> 512 mb) and restarted installer after reboot. Now it imported schema in 12 mins. I checked the logs, the previous time it stucked on schema 80.

Comment: No wonder it was getting stuck with 396 MB... that's absolutely not enough for Exchange 2007 on a DC. Or for Exchange 2007 *at all*.

Comment: Our Exchange 2007 server consumes 5Gb and that's for 10 users...

Answer (score 2):

1) Why are you using the x86 version? Is it a test environment?
2) Why Exchange 2007 SP1? You should really use SP3.
3) Are you installing it on a domain controller?
4) What hardware are you using?
5) Which operating system?

And,

6) No, you most definitely should ***not*** kill `lsass.exe`. ***NEVER***. It's a critical system process.

Comment: 1) Yes, testing environment 2) ok, need to consider. 3) yes 4) VMWare 5) Windows 2003 R2 SP2 x86

Comment: BTW, probably I was not clear... I am installing Exchange Server 2007 *with* SP 1, not a Service Pack.

Comment: @alex2k8, it's the same thing, you can do a full install from a "service pack" download. It's not a standalone service pack installer.